# Expanding profile description not accessible after opening question from it

Tags: bug, profile-page, android-app

As explanation I will show the problem at PPCG's Dennis' profile.

On my phone, after accessing his particular PPCG profile (or any other) I can expand the description with the appearing three dots.

He has a few questions linked in there and after looking at one (great reads!) and going back (either using the button of my device or from the app) the option is not given to expand the description to check the other questions he has got listed there.

The questions do not have to be from the description. For me this also appears when clicking onto his top posts; therefore not limited to a few profiles.

It does not matter whether the description has been expanded before or not.

- App Version: 1.0.89
- Device Manufacturer: Samsung
- Device Model: SM-G900F

  - OS Version: 6.0.1 (G900FXXS1CPK1)

Comment: I get this problem too, using LG